# How can we say "I'm sorry" apart from "lo siento"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

So far the only way I know to say "I'm sorry" is "lo siento." However, this gets repetitive rather quickly, and sometimes I'm looking for a stronger form of an apology. What other ways are there to apologize in spanish? If you are apologizing for an extremely terrible thing you've done, would you use a different phrase? How do native speakers apologize or convey regret for things they've done?

Comment: You can also say "lo siento" + something big, like "muchísimo".

Comment: "Lo siento" implica mas bien el sentido de empatia que el arrepentimiento.

Comment: I made a YouTube video that explains how to apologize in Spanish. It explains which context is appropriate for different apologies like when to use lo siento or perdón. Hope this helps! https://youtu.be/mneRXgho_FQ

Answer (score 15):

Well at least in Mexico is not common to say "lo siento" instead we say "**perdón**" for apologizing. The only part that I've heard "**lo siento**" is in **movies** or **telenovelas**.

A stronger version of "perdón" is "**perdóname**" or "**discúlpame**". You can add "**por favor**" at the beginning or at the end of the sentence.

Here some examples:

> Perdóname por haberte mentido.
>
> Por favor perdóname.
>
> Perdón por no haber hecho caso.
>
> Perdón.
>
> Discúlpame por favor.

Comment: All of these sound ok in Argentina. But also "lo siento (mucho)"

Comment: It works the same way in Spain

Comment: I think we use "lo siento" when we really make a mess, and "perdon" in every other I'm sorry moment

Comment: As a good spanish, you must learn to say it in the way you don't say it.. xD, "la he cagado", is really colloquial, and if you put sad face, can be understood like that :P, and you don't have to say "sorry".

Answer (score 7):

'**Sentir**', '**perdonar**', '**disculpar**', and even '**dispensar**' are all used depending on the reason for your apology:

> Lo sentimos, este teléfono ha sido desconectado.
>
> Lo sentimos, la lluvia ha arruinado el paseo.

You're just being polite, it is not really your fault and beyond your control.

> Discúlpame por haber llegado un poco tarde.
>
> Estamos remodelando, disculpe las molestias.
>
> Disculpe, ¿sabe a qué hora empieza la fiesta?

This is the equivalent of 'excuse me'. You are responsible for the action, but it is a small or easily-justifiable matter.

> Perdóname por no haber ido a nuestra cita.
>
> *Perdón por pisarte la mano

You are responsible for the action, and it is a big deal.

Other words to keep in mind:

*'Dispensar'* is used by old people in Mexico, it is the equivalent of *'disculpar'* and it is disappearing but will remain in written works.

*'Con permiso'* is the active and physical version of 'excuse me'. It always involves physical movement, like when leaving/entering a room or reaching in front of someone to grab something.

*'Pesar'* is used when something weighs heavily on you and is much deeper:

> Me pesa mucho no haberte creído.

Last but not least, *'dar el pésame'* is what you would say to someone who has lost someone:

> Mi más sentido pésame por la pérdida de tu papá.

Comment: Very similar in Spain, but here we also use `Lo siento` when the action is our fault, apart from the use you have explain. `¡Lo siento! no sabía que estabas detrás de la puerta. ¿Te he hecho daño?`. If you really regret what you have done you can also add `perdona` or `perdóname`at the end: `¡Lo siento! no sabía que estabas detrás de la puerta. ¿Te he hecho daño? Perdona`

Answer (score 5):

In Argentina, we just emphasize "Lo siento" (or "lo lamento")

> Lo siento mucho
>
> Lo siento muchísimo

Alfredo's alternatives are also ok.

Comment: +1 for `lo lamento`

Answer (score 3):

Other alternative, stronger than just "lo siento":

```
lo lamento / lo lamento mucho / lo lamento muchsísimo
```

It's also more formal than "lo siento"

Comment: I would add that 'lamentarse' is not only stronger but also more formal.

Answer (score 2):

Yet even another more formal way could be:

> Te pido disculpas.
>
> Te pido perdón.

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

- Lo siento mucho
- Siento
- Lamento
- Mi más sentido pésame

Though, I'm sorry has different meanings depend on the context that you use, it can also be used to ask someone repeat something, to express condolences, to object, or to get someone's attention. And in different context, you would use different expressions to say "I'm sorry".

Comment: Hello Kayla and welcome to [spanish.se]. Instead of posting links to other pages -which is likely to have your posts marked as spam-, select the relevant parts of those pages and quote them in here. Check [answer] and [tour] to get a full view of how we like answers in here.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you could say

> Perdón
>
> Lo lamento

Perdón is more used if you accidentally hurt or bump into a person. If you want you can add *muchísimo* to make it sound like you mean it from your bottom of your heart.